# Trying to fix a hard drive and I'm a little lost Mac OSX 10.13.2

Tags: mac

[image]

Please can someone help me read this.. Im trying to repair a 4TB hard drive.

Comment: Not ignoring the very good people on here, but if you take your question to "Ask Different" they ALL love Apple there !

Comment: ...but don't leave this one open once you've asked on the other ;)

Answer (score 0):

May I ask how you got to this point? Did you try booting into Recovery Mode and using Disc Utilities to repair your disk? You can access Recovery Mode by restarting and holding down the "Command" and "R" keys. You should get a menu of options. Select "Disc Utilities" and go from there.